# react-native start gives me "Watchman error: too many pending cache jobs"

Tags: react-native, watchman

## Problem

When I create a bundle - the watchman crawl initially fails with "`too many pending cache jobs`", which seems to slow down the bundling process:

```
$ react-native start --reset-cache
```

> Loading dependency graph...jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
>
> Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
>
> Error: Watchman error: too many pending cache jobs. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html

Also, these may be related:

- I can get rid of the error by excluding `node_modules` from the watch config
- Without the error, and the bundler starts in **20 seconds**
- With the error, the craw takes 4 seconds, but the bundler starts in **4 minutes**

## Background

### Pre-bundle scripts

I run these before the bundler, to attempt to get more stability:

```sh
watchman watch-del-all
watchman shutdown-server
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=5242880
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=524288
```

### Watchman config file

I set my `.watchconfig` file to be extra permissable:

```
{
  "ignore_dirs": [],
  "fsevents_latency": 0.5,
  "fsevents_try_resync": true
}
```

### Watchman log

The crawl **does complete**, within a few seconds according to the full log

```sh
$ tail -f /usr/local/var/run/watchman/coolman-state/log
```

```
22:08:24,193: [client=0x7ff4a9686d98:stm=0x7ff4a9b2de00:pid=0] send_error_response: too many pending cache jobs
22:08:24,340: [listener] Watchman 4.9.0 <no build info set> starting up on coolman
22:08:24,341: [listener] path /Users/coolman/project/react-native-app is on filesystem type apfs
22:08:24,342: [listener] root /Users/coolman/project/react-native-app using watcher mechanism fsevents (auto was requested)
22:08:24,344: [listener] file limit is 2560 kern.maxfilesperproc=524288
22:08:24,344: [listener] raised file limit to 524288
22:08:24,345: [listener] launchd: "sock" wasn't present in Sockets
22:08:28,805: [io 0x7f87ba000818 /Users/coolman/project/react-native-app] PERF: {"ru_nvcsw": 1460, "ru_nsignals": 0, "ru_msgrcv": 0, "ru_msgsnd": 0, "ru_inblock": 0, "ru_majflt": 0, "ru_nswap": 0, "ru_minflt": 28103, "ru_ixrss": 0, "ru_maxrss": 115109888, "system_time": 2.9349970000000001, "user_time": 1.327971, "elapsed_time": 4.4614079999999996, "pid": 29414, "ru_idrss": 0, "meta": {"root": {"watcher": "fsevents", "ticks": 2, "number": 1, "case_sensitive": false, "recrawl_count": 0, "path": "/Users/coolman/project/react-native-app"}}, "version": "4.9.0", "ru_oublock": 0, "ru_nivcsw": 2171, "start_time": 1564952904.3444469, "description": "full-crawl"}
22:08:28,805: [io 0x7f87ba000818 /Users/coolman/project/react-native-app] crawl complete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Adding `"content_hash_max_items": 500000` to my `.watchmanconfig` solved it for me.

### Explanation:

> Sounds like you need to tune the metadata cache size(s) for your workload; that error occurs when watchman is attempting to insert more cache entries than are configured.
>
> You can specify larger values in your `.watchmanconfig` file:
>
> - `content_hash_max_items` is related to the `content.sha1hex` metadata and defaults to `131072`.  A related option is `content_hash_max_warm_per_settle` which defaults to `1024` and which causes up to this many items to be assessed on each settle.
> - `symlink_target_max_items` defaults to `32768`.  This cache is used for `readlink` in the case that queries ask for the symlink target.  This is less likely to be your issue.
>
> I would suggest running `find /Users/coolman/project/react-native-app | wc -l` to get an upper bound on the number of files currently in your project and use that to size these caches; if you have more files than those defaults then you should raise those cache settings accordingly.
>
> I do not recommend changing the `fsevents_latency` parameter from the default; can you share more context on what led you to change it?
>
> [Github](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/737#issuecomment-518717721)